# File upload validation - to unlink from tmp or not

Tags: php, file-upload

Just a quick question on best practice.

If my website visitors are uploading files that fail file validation (too large, wrong filetype etc.) is it safer/ more efficient to programatically delete the file from the servers tmp directory? Or do I just let the purge cycle performed by the server take care of it?

Many thanks
Phill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

So, you could omit it, however:

> Whatever the logic, you should either delete the file from the temporary directory or move it elsewhere.

... it's always nice to be explicit in your script. In short: you don't *have* to, but I would.

Comment: Hi Wrikken. Many thanks for your response, I've been looking for the answer for this for some time! Thanks again.